# Regex or conversion for 'YYYY-MMM-DD'

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex, t-sql, ssis

I'm working with data in `t-SQL` and in order to automate my package in `SSIS` that will process each file with each given date, I need to figure out the `regex` or conversion for a file such as **'leads_2019-Dec-22'** so the package can complete.

So far this is as far as I've gone, however this only works for `'YYYY-MM-DD'` formats. I'm unable to change the format from the data loader tool I have, so there's no easy fix to this other.

```
@[User::UploadedFile] = 
REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@[User::UploadedFileName], "yyyy", 
(DT_STR,4,1252)DATEPART( "yyyy" , getdate())),"mm",RIGHT("0"+ 
(DT_STR,4,1252)DATEPART("mm",getdate()),2)), "dd", RIGHT("0"+ 
(DT_STR,4,1252)DATEPART("dd",getdate()),2)), "hh",  right("0" + 
(DT_STR,4,1252)DATEPART("Hh",getdate()),2)             )
```

Has anyone dealt with this before and if so, how did/would you solve this using an Expression?

Comment: Are dates always in the same formats?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no `regex`es in ms sql. you may search SO for solution though.

Comment: If you want to convert a date to yyyy-mm-dd then you simply need to convert the date to a varchar using the correct conversion code. Just look up the sql date conversion codes to find the right one, and truncate or replace characters like spaces if you need to.

Comment: Can you please explain the significance of `(DT_STR,4,1252)`?

Comment: yyyy-mm-dd is ISO8601. `CONVERT( VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 23 )` should do the trick. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#date-and-time-styles

Comment: @robbpriestley I found [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/cast-ssis-expression?view=sql-server-ver15) about `DT-STR`

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server does not support regular expressions.
However, the format used in the file name is very similar to a format you can use with `convert` to get the actual date from it's string representation.

The format convert supports under style `106` is `dd mom yyyy` - meaning all you have to do is isolate the date part from the string, replace the hyphens with spaces, and convert.

Please note that if the default language of the current login is not English, you might get errors because the month names depends on the language settings.
This is why I've included the `set language` statement in my code:

```
SET LANGUAGE us_english;

DECLARE @FileName varchar(20) = 'leads_2019-Dec-22';

SELECT CONVERT(Date, REPLACE(RIGHT(@FileName, 11), '-', ' '), 106);
```

Result:

```
2019-12-22
```

Comment: SQL-Server does not allow regular expressions, but SSIS does.

Answer (score 1):

If you can be sure, now and forever, that this will never-ever run in systems with a different culture you can use easy conversions or set the language and culture for a session specifically.

But - if ever run on different systems - this might pass all your internal tests and may break in production with silly errors.

Culture specific approaches (and even worse: language specific ones) are very dangerous...

To overcome this you can use the following culture-safe approach (but it will be slower than simple conversions):

```
--Your question is not clear for me about the actual input.
--The string I use here seems to be your needed outcome...
--However, you will get the ghist how you can approach this issue with any given value...  
DECLARE @TheFileName varchar(20) = 'leads_2019-Dec-22';

--not needed, just for testing... (in Germany "Dec" needs to be "Dez"...)
SET LANGUAGE GERMAN;

SELECT FORMAT(TRY_PARSE(RIGHT(@TheFileName,11) AS DATE USING 'en-us'),'yyyy-MMM-dd','en-us');
```

You have three obstacles:

First is to cut off the pure date. I do this by using `RIGHT` assuming we always need the rigth-most eleven characters.
Second is to get a date-typed value out of this. `TRY_PARSE()` accepts a culture parameter to ensure correct reading.
Third is to create the correct output. Here I use `FORMAT()`, which again allows for a specific culture.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the an output string in `YYYY-MM-DD` format from a variable called UploadedFileName that has data like **'leads_2019-Dec-22'**, you can just replace the "leads_" part and convert the rest to a date. Then you can parse the date to change it to the desired `YYYY-MM-DD` format:

```
(DT_WSTR, 4) YEAR((DT_DATE) REPLACE(@[User::UploadedFileName],"leads_","")) + "-" +
(DT_WSTR, 2) MONTH((DT_DATE) REPLACE(@[User::UploadedFileName],"leads_","")) + "-" +
(DT_WSTR, 2) DAY((DT_DATE) REPLACE(@[User::UploadedFileName],"leads_",""))
```